# Optimized regular expression search in a text corpus in Python

Tags: python, regex

Here is my requirement in python:

I literally load a dictionary - say from /usr/share/dict/words (not to be confused with dictionary type) and use it to search for valid words. At the moment I am doing as follows:

```
dict_list  = open('dictionary', 'r').read().split()

def search_dictionary(key):
    p=re.compile(key)
    # Comment: Is 'key' a prefix for a valid word in dictionary?
    # If yes, return True, else return False
    tmp_list = [x for x in dict_list if bool(p.match(x))]
    if not tmp_list:
        ....
    else:
        ....
```

Note that search_dictionary can be called large number of times and this is a bottleneck at the moment. Is there a more efficient way to do this string search? Like say pre-compiling dictionary. One can think of a dictionary attack use case. I am relatively a starter.

EDIT: I have updated the code with comments. As suggested in comments, I am possibly doing more work than needed.

Comment: This is a great question, but unfortunately there's a whole field of research in indexing text, so it's really rather too broad in its present state.

Comment: I imagine `if  p.match(x)` is sufficient,  are you looking for individual words?

Comment: I think you may be doing a lot more work than you need to, can you add some input and expected output

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ah, good catch. I just want to return a True/False stating that 'key' is a prefix for valid word. So in that sense, I realize i am doing more work. I think a good algorithm will be to return True after first match.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I am sort of wondering if python has some built-in similar re.compile() that i should have used instead.

Comment: @NathanTuggy The property to use is perhaps take advantage of the lexicographic ordering of words in dictionary. So instead of scanning all elements of dict_list, if there is a string search that just hits the index of first letter of key, then it would be great

Comment: **Show us 20 of your regexes!** Do they all start with letters? character classes? numbers? lookbehind assertions? whitespace? something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm runs in O(n) time with large constants. This seems so wrong, when a simple binary search could do O(lg n). If your regex does not contain special characters, why not:

```
import bisect
with open('dictionary') as f:
    dictionary = f.read().split()

    # .sort is slow, so better to sort
    # words on disk! And/or run many searches
    # for one invocation
    dictionary.sort()

def bisect_search(key):
    i = bisect.bisect_left(dictionary, key)
    if i != len(dictionary):
        return dictionary[i].startswith(key)

    return False
```

Sorts the array, and then finds the lexicographically "smallest" word for which `word >= key` and sees if it is a prefix for the given key.

Speed test against Padraic's *first letter from dictionary, then linear search*:

```
In [1]: %timeit bisect_search('thu')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 µs per loop

In [2]: %timeit search_dictionary('thu')
1000 loops, best of 3: 595 µs per loop
```

with 146880 words, and 5760 words starting with `t`.

Comment: The `dictionary.sort()` step can probably be eliminated, since such word list files are normally already sorted. And if not, it makes sense to sort it once, and save the sorted version to disk, rather than sorting it each time you run the searching script.

Comment: Thanks. Binary search helped!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop on the first match use [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) which will short circuit as soon as we find a match, in your code you always go through every word in the dictionary even if you get a match on the first word, you also build a list unnecessarily:

```
dict_list  = open('dictionary').read().split()

def search_dictionary(key):
    p = re.compile(key)
    if any(p.match(x) for x in dict_list):
    .....
```

You should also preferably only be creating your dictionary once not every time you call the function. Define it at the start of your code and  pass it as a parameter if needed.

If you want to find prefixes using `str.startswith` would probably  be faster:

```
if any(x.startswith(key) for x in dict_list):
```

To optimise the startswith calls:

```
check = str.startswith
if any(check(x, key) for x in dict_list):
```

Or if it can appear anywhere just use in:

```
if any(key in x for x in dict_list):
```

using cpython2.7 using the optimised str.startswith method seems more efficient:

```
In [15]: s ="efficient"

In [16]: timeit p.match(s)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 359 ns per loop

In [17]: check = str.startswith

In [18]: timeit check(s,"eff")
1000000 loops, best of 3: 212 ns per loop
```

The difference for non matches is roughly the same

If you make a an actual dict from  your dictionary where the keys are from a-z and the values are lists of words starting with the key, you can use the first letter from each `key` in your function  to do lookups only searching the words that start with the same letter.

```
from collections import defaultdict
word_dict = defaultdict(list)

with open("/usr/share/dict/words") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip().lower()
        word_dict[line[0]].append(line)
```

You can see an example output use a key "z":

```
word_dict["z"]
['z', "z's", 'zachariah', "zachariah's", 'zachary', "zachary's", 'zachery', "zachery's", 'zagreb', "zagreb's", 'zaire', "zaire's", 'zairian', 'zambezi', "zambezi's", 'zambia', "zambia's", 'zambian', "zambian's", 'zambians', 'zamboni', 'zamenhof', "zamenhof's", 'zamora', 'zane', "zane's", 'zanuck', "zanuck's", 'zanzibar', "zanzibar's", 'zapata', 'zaporozhye', 'zapotec', 'zappa', "zappa's", 'zara', "zara's", 'zebedee', 'zechariah', 'zedekiah', "zedekiah's", 'zedong', "zedong's", 'zeffirelli', "zeffirelli's", 'zeke', "zeke's", 'zelig', 'zelma', "zelma's", 'zen', "zen's", 'zenger', "zenger's", 'zeno', "zeno's", 'zens', 'zephaniah', 'zephyrus', 'zeppelin', 'zest', "zest's", 'zeus', "zeus's", 'zhengzhou', 'zhivago', "zhivago's", 'zhukov', 'zibo', "zibo's", 'ziegfeld', 'ziegler', "ziegler's", 'ziggy', "ziggy's", 'zimbabwe', "zimbabwe's", 'zimbabwean', "zimbabwean's", 'zimbabweans', 'zimmerman', "zimmerman's", 'zinfandel', "zinfandel's", 'zion', "zion's", 'zionism', "zionism's", 'zionisms', 'zionist', "zionist's", 'zionists', 'zions', 'ziploc', 'zn', "zn's", 'zoe', "zoe's", 'zola', "zola's", 'zollverein', 'zoloft', 'zomba', "zomba's", 'zorn', 'zoroaster', "zoroaster's", 'zoroastrian', "zoroastrian's", 'zoroastrianism', "zoroastrianism's", 'zoroastrianisms', 'zorro', "zorro's", 'zosma', "zosma's", 'zr', "zr's", 'zsigmondy', 'zubenelgenubi', "zubenelgenubi's", 'zubeneschamali', "zubeneschamali's", 'zukor', "zukor's", 'zulu', "zulu's", 'zulus', 'zuni', 'zwingli', "zwingli's", 'zworykin', 'zyrtec', "zyrtec's", 'zyuganov', "zyuganov's", 'zürich', "zürich's", 'z', 'zanier', 'zanies', 'zaniest', 'zaniness', "zaniness's", 'zany', "zany's", 'zap', "zap's", 'zapped', 'zapping', 'zaps', 'zeal', "zeal's", 'zealot', "zealot's", 'zealots', 'zealous', 'zealously', 'zealousness', "zealousness's", 'zebra', "zebra's", 'zebras', 'zebu', "zebu's", 'zebus', 'zed', "zed's", 'zeds', 'zenith', "zenith's", 'zeniths', 'zephyr', "zephyr's", 'zephyrs', 'zeppelin', "zeppelin's", 'zeppelins', 'zero', "zero's", 'zeroed', 'zeroes', 'zeroing', 'zeros', 'zest', "zest's", 'zestful', 'zestfully', 'zests', 'zeta', 'zigzag', "zigzag's", 'zigzagged', 'zigzagging', 'zigzags', 'zilch', "zilch's", 'zillion', "zillion's", 'zillions', 'zinc', "zinc's", 'zinced', 'zincing', 'zincked', 'zincking', 'zincs', 'zing', "zing's", 'zinged', 'zinger', "zinger's", 'zingers', 'zinging', 'zings', 'zinnia', "zinnia's", 'zinnias', 'zip', "zip's", 'zipped', 'zipper', "zipper's", 'zippered', 'zippering', 'zippers', 'zippier', 'zippiest', 'zipping', 'zippy', 'zips', 'zircon', "zircon's", 'zirconium', "zirconium's", 'zircons', 'zit', "zit's", 'zither', "zither's", 'zithers', 'zits', 'zodiac', "zodiac's", 'zodiacal', 'zodiacs', 'zombi', "zombi's", 'zombie', "zombie's", 'zombies', 'zombis', 'zonal', 'zone', "zone's", 'zoned', 'zones', 'zoning', 'zonked', 'zoo', "zoo's", 'zoological', 'zoologist', "zoologist's", 'zoologists', 'zoology', "zoology's", 'zoom', "zoom's", 'zoomed', 'zooming', 'zooms', 'zoos', 'zucchini', "zucchini's", 'zucchinis', 'zwieback', "zwieback's", 'zygote', "zygote's", 'zygotes']
```

So fetch the vals use `word_dict[key]` to get the appropriate values:

```
def search_dictionary(key):
    check = str.startswith
    vals = word_dict[key[0]]
    if any(check(x, key) for x in vals):
```

Not sure if you have considered case or not so you may want to remove the lower call depending on what you want.

Comment: No, 'key' can be a prefix of a valid word. For e.g., key can be 'hel' and is thus a prefix of a valid word 'hello'.

Comment: Thanks for the first fix though. I'll try it if it makes any difference (I think it should make some difference).

Comment: @Ram, it should make a big difference on average. It only checks a condition each time no storing multiple booleans like you list and will break if we find a match

Comment: Yes, I create the dictionary just once and is a global variable.

Comment: are you just searching for prefixes?

Comment: whole words are also fine. For e.g., 'h', 'he', 'hel', 'hell', 'hello' are acceptable. The idea is the item being searched has a potential for forming a valid word.

Comment: Is re.match() inefficient? I initially planned to use startswith() however looking at the possibility that my 'key' can be compiled (could be faster), I opted for re.match()

Comment: @Ram, not sure really, one trick to try is use `check = str.startswith` outside the `any` and use `if check(x,key)`  instead of if x.startswith..., that should be more efficient. Best way is to run some tests and time them

Comment: Since a dictionary is lexicographically aligned, I am wondering if that feature can be exploited someway.

Comment: if the word starts with `a` and you are in `b's` in your dictionary  you should not go any further.